# My card icons are not the same position when the paragraph is is bigger or small

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, tailwind-css

[This is my cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFZrL.png)

I trying to giv it a relative position and parent div absolute but is not working

I trying to giv it a relative position and parent div absolute but is not working

I trying to giv it a relative position and parent div absolute but is not working

I trying to giv it a relative position and parent div absolute but is not working

Comment: Please share a sample of the HTML and CSS code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Give a bottom margin to each card like
`margin-bottom:20px` using css.
then, all cards will align to the bottom. And it won't affect when paragraph size changes.

Comment: I fixed it by giving the parent card dev  is relative position and absolute for icons with bottom value